# Measure separate cpu core usage for a process?

Tags: c#, multicore, cpu-usage

I'd like to monitor my apps and see what cores, and what percentage of each core, they are using. I know of PerformanceCounter, but I can't seem to find a way to get the cpu core usage for each process separately..

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can't you get the processor % per system core for a process/application as a performance counter.

Comment: as far as i know not? i looked trough all the counters couldn't find any that suit the job. if you could point me in the right direction that would be very kind ;) ty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process Exporer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and check here for other ideas [Tracking CPU and Memory usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process)

Comment: basicly what im trying to achieve is a process affinity & priority manager like process lasso kinda does. But therefor i need to measure process cpu core load. anyone ? thnx in advance