# memory leak in opencv functions

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been noticing that my programs' memory usage keeps increasing pointlessly at times. Specially when i am using `cvWaitKey(0)`, my program tends to shoot memory usage in 10 seconds to a huge size.

Is there a fix for this, or this is an OpenCv bug?

I have a simple function called `Show_Image`, to we which have set a callback function to get the pixel values:

```
void Show_Image(IplImage *img)
{
    cvNamedWindow("IMAGE_WINDOW", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    cvSetMouseCallback("IMAGE_WINDOW", GETPIXEL , (void*)img);
    cvShowImage("IMAGE_WINDOW", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("IMAGE_WINDOW");
}
```

Comment: Post a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem (http://sscce.org). Your current description is far too vague to be investigated by anything but guesswork and prior experience.

Comment: @Mankarse - posted relevant code... please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no error and no workaround for this. When you call cvWaitkey(), the function processes all the windows message queue. And because you have a mouse callback, it always processes something there. This, combined with the weak capability of the system to show the real memory usage for a process, can give you a false leak alarm.

However, to find the source of the problem, add in your program a line of code, like below

```
getchar();
```

Wait for the process memory to increase, then press any key to get out of the message loop in cvWaitKey(), and then wait for a minute in the getchar() function. If the memory did not go down in that minute, it may be a leak. Feel free to fill a ticket in the openCV bug tracker https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/wiki

Also try different methods to measure the increase in memory:
[How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)
or 
[Tracking CPU and Memory usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process)