# How to get the memory usage of a process executed by proc_open()

Tags: php, windows

I have to measure the memory usage and the execution time of the process executed by proc_open(). Measuring the time is not that hard, but I can't find any method to get the memory usage. (the program can terminate very quickly)

Is there any method to get the memory usage of a process executed by `proc_open()`?

My OS is windows for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@love-paper, make use of the `descriptorspec` parameters for proc_open to write the memory usage to a file, that you can then read in.

**parent process**

```
$child_id = uniqid();
$descriptorspec = array(
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/$child_id", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);
proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec);

$memory_used = file_get_contents("/tmp/$child_id");
```

**child process**

```
// at the end of the script
file_put_contents('php://stderr', memory_get_peak_usage(true));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just a process, not made by php. I'm sorry that I didn't mention it.

Comment: Can you modify the child process to record its memory usage, or is it a black box?

Comment: It's a black box, so I can't do anything with it.

Comment: If you are on a linux box, then use either `/usr/bin/time -v` or `memusg`. See this earlier answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process

Comment: I already saw that, but my server is on windows.  I tried to use 'tasklist', but the process terminates too fast.

Comment: Have you tried to use perfmon.exe [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process]

Comment: I've tried it, but the processes are created and deleted by the script so many times, so I'm not sure it's okay to get the memory usage.

Comment: Why do you have to measure the memory usage of the process? Is it for scale purposes, so you can how the system resources are being used?

Comment: I'm making a tester of my program (implemented by C++), which gives my program some inputs and gets outputs from the program. I used PHP because I wanted to test on the web.

Comment: In that case, I would use your C++ program to log its cpu and memory usage. Then parse the log in a separate step.