# cmd memory usage

Tags: c++, c, cmd

I'm having a project which is about making an easy grader using windows cmd.
   `a.exe < input.txt>output.txt`.
Is there anyway I could determine the memory usage and time elapse?

Comment: Can I get the memory usage from task manager to use in my application?

Comment: Resource Monitor under Task Manager is what you're looking for I believe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Answer (score 2):

For memory:

```
tasklist /fi "memusage gt 30000" | findstr "yourapp.exe yourapp2.exe*" | SORT >> memory_log.txt
```

For time:

```
echo powershell -Command Measure-Command {cmd /c '%thecmd%'} ^| FINDSTR /L /C:"Seconds           :" /L /C:"Minutes           :" > %temp%\timeexec.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the powershell [Measure-Command cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx) which will give you time. I don't know if it'll take redirection, but if you put your command into a batch file you could run something like so:

```
start-process file-to-measure.bat -Wait
```

Looking at this question: [Tracking CPU and Memory usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process) it looks like a WMI script might do what you want.