# Monitorig system (windows): cpu and disk load log

Tags: windows, performance, monitoring

I'm developing applications (services) for Windows and sometimes have problem with performance and recources (especially with MsSql). I need to know which *service*, *application* or OS *component*, developed by my or someone else, makes load CPU or HDD at some moment in past.

I whant to be able to do it using some kind of stored data (log), better with grafics.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process

Comment: Windows Performance Toolkit shows in detail which process/thread causes CPU/disk usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Perfmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc749154(v=ws.11)) will be you built in friend!

you can either log current performance counters in a user session or let a background service track your preselected counters and you can check that afterwards.

you will find tons of explanations how to user perfmon. It is part of every windows since NT4.

Comment: is there way to find out which process makes load cpu or disk at some moment in past?